# Email sent using SES going to spam folder when display name is used

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, dkim, dmarc

I just started using AWS SES to send emails from my application. I verified my domain in the SES dashboard, and the test emails worked fine.

I'm using the .Net SDK to make API calls through SendEmail. When I set the "source" attribute to `johndoe@domain.com` it goes straight to my inbox, but when I set it to `John Doe <johndoe@domain.com>` it goes straight to spam and DKIM/DMARC fail.

Is there a way to set a display name on my emails that does not trigger a DKIM/DMARC fail?

Comment: Do you have the entire domain validated in SES, or just the email address?

Comment: @MarkB I have the entire domail validated, with DKIM enabled

Answer (score 0):

Apparently only having DKIM enabled was not enough for the "display name" property to pass DMARC checks. When I configured a custom domain on SES "MAIL FROM" property, it started working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).